# how to load Maps after onDeviceReady function in iOS Cordova based app?

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-build, onload

I want to Load maps after oDeviceReady function to avoid a Permission alert to access Maps in iOS which shows complete bundle path location as shown below:(iOS Cordova 3.8.0 version)

[image]

For this I have used

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
   <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/hashmap.js"></script>
```

After head tag:

```
 </head>
 <body onload="onBodyLoad();">//Called onload
```

After this

```
  function onBodyLoad()
  {
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  }


   function onDeviceReady(){      
      return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);       
     document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);     
    }

  function initialize() 
 {
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   if (navigator.geolocation) 
   {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) 
      {
      LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("estimate"), mapOptions);
     infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
     marker =new google.maps.Marker({position:LatLng,map:map});
     getAddress(p.coords.latitude,p.coords.longitude);

    }
  }
}

    //This line is making to display complete Bundle path loaction
    //Where as calling this line to avoid error in onDeviceready, My maps are not loading
    // Suggest me where should I call this line of code to avoid this alert
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    function getAddress(lat, lng)
    {
        //Code to get address
     }
```

Can anyone suggest me where should I call below line to avoid this type alert;

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Other than this alert my code is working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you installed the geolocation plugin with

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

and change your code to

```
function onBodyLoad() {

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

}


function onDeviceReady(){      
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);       
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);     
}

function initialize(p) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("estimate"), mapOptions);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    marker =new google.maps.Marker({position:LatLng,map:map});
    getAddress(p.coords.latitude,p.coords.longitude);
}
```

Comment: did you install the plugin from the cli? and remove one of the cordova.js, you have 2

Comment: Yes I have installed from CMI and I have one  cordova.js

Comment: Actually if I m using "google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);" any where other than its current place in code like onDeviceReady map is not loading..Can you please suggest me any alternative way to remove this kind of error alert. It is showing js file complete location

Comment: can you update your question with your current code? on the code you posted you have two cordova.js, and you are calling initializa multiple times, you have to call it just how I told you, remove the window load line and any other that calls the initialize, and leave only the one from onDeviceReady

Comment: thanks a lot..It is working now ( getting default iOS map permission alert )after removing window load line..

Answer (score 0):

first of all add this plugin using command prompt(cmd)

**cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation**

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() 
    {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        codeAddress();
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    if (navigator.geolocation) 
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        });
    }

});
</script>
```